# How to compute summation over distinct indices fast in R?

Tags: r, sum

I want to compute

```
Tn<-sum((X[k]-X[l]) *(X[s]-X[t])) *(Y[k]-Y[l]) *(Y[s]-Y[t])
```

with k, l, s, t distinct.

I tried this way:

```
Tn1<-sum((X[k]-X[l]) *(X[s]-X[t])) *(Y[k]-Y[l]) *(Y[s]-Y[t])
Tn2<-sum((X[k]-X[s]) *(X[l]-X[t])) *(Y[k]-Y[s]) *(Y[l]-Y[t])
Tn3<-sum((X[k]-X[t]) *(X[s]-X[l])) *(Y[k]-Y[t]) *(Y[s]-Y[l])
Tn<-(Tn1+Tn2+Tn3) / 3
```

where the summations are over all indices with no restriction (by some computation, this is equal to the original one), but it is very slow. Is there any way to compute summation over distinct indices fast in R?

Comment: Do you only have 4 indices? Or is this in a `for` loop? How big is your `X`? A little bit of sample data would help to understand the problem. How slow is it, and how fast do you need it to be? The operations you show should all be quite fast...

Comment: @GregorThomas: Yes, only 4 indices, not in a for loop. I just wondering whether there is some more fast operations to do such summation over distinct indices.

Comment: On my system, running your code using X and Y vectors of 100M elements each, I get 6 microseconds per iteration, approx 140,000 per second. Can you provide more context about the problem? I guess "slow" is relative, but some more code / example data / explanation might help you get more relevant suggestions.